# Trouble creating dropdown containing instances from another Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble creating a new Post object that belongs to a Company. A post belongs to a Company, and a Company has many Posts.
When a User creates a new Post, he has the option of selecting a Company that is associated with that Post:

```
<%= form.collection_select(:company, @companies, :id, :name ) %>
```

When a User submits this form, the following error appears:

```
Company(#39435240) expected, got String(#9332080)
```

Inside of the request headers, we are sending the Company id. Should it be sending an id?
Here is the complete request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ7O26zoDPh5PB7Zk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utf8"

âœ“
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ7O26zoDPh5PB7Zk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[title]"

fdasfa
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ7O26zoDPh5PB7Zk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[content]"

fdsafsda
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ7O26zoDPh5PB7Zk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[company]"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ7O26zoDPh5PB7Zk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[image]"; filename="nike.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif


------WebKitFormBoundaryJ7O26zoDPh5PB7Zk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="commit"

Create New Post
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ7O26zoDPh5PB7Zk--
```

It's sending the Company id of 1 (which is the only Company that exists in my test database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should be `:company_id` and not `:company`

```
<%= form.collection_select(:company_id, @companies, :id, :name ) %>
```

Comment: When I change the first argument to company_id, I get the following error when trying to load the Post: undefined method `company_id' for #<Post:0x00000005170840>

Comment: that is weird. you said posts belong_to a company? so that should follow that posts should have a company_id unless you specify a different foreign key?

Comment: I explicitly set this line belongs_to :company inside of my Post model.

Comment: yep. but that expects you to have a company_id column in your posts table. this column will be a foreign key and will be used to associate a company to a post.

Comment: Ah, I need to create the column. I only added the associations to the Models. I totally forgot about that.

Comment: just remember that a belongs_to association needs a matching association_id column or whatever foreign key you specified.